# What is the initial value of a static/global enum variable?

Tags: c, variables, initialization, boolean, declaration

e.g. quake engines have

```
typedef enum {qfalse, qtrue} qboolean;
```

When one does

```
static qboolean variable;
```

Is the variable's start-up value 0?

Comment: `C` automatically initialized all static variables to `0` or `false`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

static and global variables are cleared by default, if there is no value assigned at initialization.

In your example `variable` will have the enum's equivalent of `0`, i.e. `qfalse`.

Comment: OK, I just didn't know if enum is a special case since I hadn't read it mentioned explicitly.

Comment: correct if by cleared you mean 'initialized to 0' (in case of scalar types); enumerated types are arithmetic and thus zeroed as well, even if 0 is not part of the enumeration!